# Setting all values of table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to set every value of a table at the same time. It is something like this:

```
$items = Item::where("user_id",$user_id)->get();

foreach($items as $item){
$item->propiety = 5;
$item->save();
}
```

This works but I wonder if there is a better way to do it with Eloquent, as I can think better ways to do it with SQL.

Comment: `Item::where('user_id', $user_id)->update(['propiety' => 5])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it this way:

```
Item::where("user_id", $user_id)->update(['propiety' => 5]);
```